# Postfix Mail Server & hosted Gmail relay setup

Tags: centos, email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I am trying to setup our web server so that it can send emails from various web apps to reset password etc. Our mail is hosted by Gmail with a custom domain eg. `mydomain.com`.

Right now emails going to various domains just sit in the mail queue. Anything that is sent to `someuser@mydomain.com` doesn't even make it to the queue.

How do I route the SMTP server through Gmail?

```
This is what I've added to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

relayhost = smtp.mydomain.com:587
smtp_tls_security_level = verified
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Should the `relayhost` be set to `smpt.gmail.com`? Do I need to change the DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want all the emails being sent via gmail, you have to set relayhost to smtp.gmail.com:587 as you wrote.

This is not enough, though.

You need to create and edit the file /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
Write a line in it like below:

```
smtp.gmail.com:587 user@example.com:password
```

where:

> user@example.com

is a valid username in your gmail hosted domain and the sender of all email routed via your mail server.

When done, create its hashed version. Run:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

and restart postfix.

Comment: ok, so I see the messages in the Queue now, but they aren't getting sent out, just sitting there. The `From` email however is not the same as the one in the `sasl_passwd` file, so maybe that's the issue now